# Most efficient way of setting a bit to 0 when 1 in another field

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

My system tracks permissions as two bitfields, allow and deny. When a bit is set in deny, the corresponding bit in allow must be set 0 when determining a users permissions.

I.e. it must be like this:

```
   110101 (allow)
   011001 (deny)
=  100100 (result)
```

I am currently looping each bit and doing a comparison, but I am wondering if this can be more elegantly expressed and faster performing.

Comment: Please describe the operation you perform on each bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't that a bitwise XOR?

```
(110101 ^ 011001) & 011001 = 100100
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `result` bit field denotes the "allowed operation", I think this should be a bitwise AND with an inverted `deny`:

`result = allow & ~deny`

I guess it will be as fast as [Pranav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646535/897968) since it also involves two operations, but if you can precompute the `~deny` values, it might be faster. Personally, I also find this solution easier to understand.